# Which Amora is mentioned most often in the Gemara?

Tags: names, talmud-gemara, rabbis, talmud-bavli, statistics

Which Amora is mentioned most often throughout Talmud Bavli?

Comment: related http://drewkaplans.blogspot.com/2011/07/rabbinic-popularity-in-mishnah-vii-top.html

Comment: @DoubleAA Is this a riddle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think there are different answers depending on the exact terms of the question; there are dozens of searches you could do on this one (e.g. "what value of X has the highest occurrences of *amar rav X*?").

As a first attempt, here are the most-common words in the Babylonian Talmud (using mechon-mamre's text as-is); I've highlighted the ones that *may* be a person's name.  The problem is that "rava" could also mean "great"; "shmuel" could be the Amora or the Biblical prophet; and so on.  I suspect Rav Ashi gets far more appearances than his colleague Ravina not necessarily by his own right, but because he also gets billing whenever his son, Mar bar Rav Ashi, appears.

From a quick glance, I'd give the most-unmistakable-occurrences prize to Abayei, except that there was more than one Abayei in the Gemara (if I'm not mistaken).  Which means the most-unmistakable-occurrences prize would then go to **Rav Huna** (I don't *think* there was more than one Rav Huna?  Anyone?)

Interesting that Rabba and his debate partner, Rabbi Nachman, appear almost exactly the same number of times.

---

אמר 35633

לא  28819

**רב    17630**

ליה 16048

אלא 15040

**רבי   13308**

על  11589

את  10198

אין 9582

ולא 9550

אומר    9078

הוא 9067

מאי 9066

כל  8682

לו  8597

בר  8207

לה  7458

ר'  7446

של  7318

**יהודה 7224**

נמי 6820

הא  6709

דאמר    6154

אי  6099

בן  5989

אבל 5768

כי  5714

משום    5350

מה  5261

זה  5217

עד  4956

או  4875

**יוחנן 4798**

היא 4700

שלא 4687

א"ל 4499

מן  4475

לי  4408

אחד 4399

דלא 4323

הכי 4270

אם  4254

**רבא   4108**

להו 3988

בין 3777

אף  3750

לאו 3726

א"ר 3631

לך  3584

בו  3412

בה  3408

מי  3387

אינו    3382

**יוסי  3287**

שאין    3271

והא 3260

דכתיב   3208

שנאמר   3150

הכא 3047

(ויקרא  3009

אדם 2860

**דרב   2828**

קא  2802

הוה 2797

ואין    2759

אחת 2758

חייב    2730

ישראל   2722

הרי 2667

רבנן    2632

סבר 2621

**שמעון 2589**

אימא    2580

**אביי  2571**

ואמר    2558

עליו    2519

**שמואל 2479**

איכא    2473

אפילו   2421

התם 2410

זו  2353

דבר 2344

ואם 2336

**אלעזר 2310**

דתניא   2302

בית 2301

אמרו    2264

ואי 2251

האי 2239

דברי    2223

תנא 2202

כאן 2196

**הונא  2196**

היה 2137

ה'  2137

טעמא    2126

מפני    2118

שני 2092

כיון    2087

(דברים  2071

יש  2068

קרא 2057

אחר 2023

**מר    1996**

כוכבים> 1982

**רבה   1971**

**נחמן  1965**

**אשי   1938**

יום 1930

דמי 1912

עליה    1889

**יוסף  1885**

**יהושע 1863**

מהו 1862

קשיא    1855

אסור    1850

בני 1836

ביה 1830

קאמר    1784

כתיב    1764

אומרים  1763

אל  1752

**פפא   1736**

**אליעזר    1721**

ורבי    1718

תניא    1711

**יצחק  1678**

**אבא   1654**

אותו    1633

לעולם   1616

דרבי    1616

לרב 1613

**אשר   1613**

וכי 1604

(שמות   1565

אני 1564

ת"ל 1531

הוי 1526

אתה 1521

להם 1517

פטור    1508

בעי 1508

בהן 1497

אמרת    1488

רחמנא   1479

מותר    1476

לומר    1472

הן  1447

למה 1446

שנים    1444

יכול    1423

מעשה    1405

**מאיר  1399**

בריה    1395

היו 1394

תורה    1393

שמע 1392

**חסדא  1392**

היכי    1390

אמרי    1385

**חייא  1384**

(במדבר  1377

ההוא    1375

שהוא    1365

דלמא    1348

קתני    1340

ת"ר 1335

דאמרי   1332

כדי 1330

גבי 1329

אלו 1323

ואחד    1303

וכל 1302

חד  1297

בעל 1297

כך  1291

לפני    1282

מקום    1279

הלכה    1277

**חנינא 1276**

איש 1276

צריך    1264

אשה 1263

בשלמא   1258

מיניה   1245

שאני    1230

**ישמעאל    1230**

Comment: Wow, great list. But why doesn't R' Yochanan win? Surely most of those references are to the Amora.

Comment: Could be R' Yochanan ben Zakai or R' Yishmael brabi Yochanan ... would have to check the numbers.  My definition of "unmistakable" was fuzzy, I know.

Comment: There actually is more than one Rav Huna in the Gemara too. For example, there's רב הונא בר נתן, the Reish Galusa in Rav Ashi's times (Gittin 59a, Zevachim 19a).

Comment: This is pretty awesome. What database did you use?

Comment: @SethJ, downloaded texts from mechon-mamre and ran my own scripts on them.

Comment: They have the Talmud on their servers now?

Comment: I just looked; I think I just never noticed, but their database says copyright 2002. Wow, major #fail on my part for not noticing.

Comment: Rav could be anyone (Rav Huna, Rav Ashi, etc).

Answer (score 3):

It is said that there are no 3 consecutive pages that do not contain a mention of Abaye or Rava. I heard that many years ago, one of the first companies to make a computer search program on Gemara "proved" this using their search functions, and offered a prize to anyone who could show otherwise. Well, someone did find 3 pages where neither of these Amoraim is mentioned (I'm not sure where); what threw the computer off was the phrase גברא רבא!

Comment: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4308/what-is-the-greatest-number-of-pages-daf-you-can-go-in-the-babylonian-talmud-wi/4309#4309

Comment: hmm... so maybe it was 6 pages...

Comment: I think @Shalom's link should be updated to: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4308/2091