# What's the Hebrew idiom for "what's his name" or "What's his face"

Tags: hebrew, names

I vaguely remember some phrase used in Torah discussions such as "moni palomy" or "moni plamoni" that means "John Doe" or "What's his name" or "John Q Public".  Seems like it was used in Ester, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be thinking of [P'loni Almoni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_placeholder_names_by_language#Hebrew) פלוני אלמוני, used first in [Ruth 4:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2904.htm) as a placeholder name. (See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15134/759) for its etymology and why it must be a placeholder name.)